# Effective SQL Query to find a given month is in between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two dates in my subscription table (`start_date` and `end_date`). I want to find out if the user is subscribed in the specified month or not? For ex: `start_date=11/20/2011 and end_date=03/10/2012`. I want to know all users who are subscribed in the month of `Feb-2012 (02/2012)`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understand, because other answers are "so" complicated, but as long as you only need to know if sbdy is subscribed within a month I would do this in a simple way:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    your_table
WHERE
    CONVERT(datetime,'2012-02-01')
        between DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, start_date), 0) 
            and DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, end_date), 0)
```

Just remember to put a first day of month within CONVERT function.

Comment: Won't find it if the start and date is 15/2/2012 to 16/2/2013 for instance

Comment: Start date `15/02/2012` changes to `01/02/2012`, end date `16/02/2013` changes to `01/02/2013`. Now, is `01/02/2012` falling in between `01/02/2012` and `01/02/2013`? The answer is yes, and as I understand this is a correct answer according to OP.

Comment: Ahhh, I see what you are doing now. It could be what the OP wants, depends on how you interpret the question. I never saw widening the start and end date boundaries to cover whole months as part of it.

Comment: What I do (`DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, some_date_value), 0)`) is actually 'truncating' the dates to full months.

Comment: Excellent. I didn't first understand what you did. After analyzing each function individually, I knew how intelligent your solution is. Thanks for your help. Kudos.

Comment: that's what I need, can you please convert that to a MySQL query? Or should I make a new question?

Answer (score 2):

Given you pass in 201202 as the month of interest as a string.

```
Declare @StartOfMonth DateTime
Declare @EndOfMonth DateTime

Set @StartOfMonth = Convert(DateTime,@MyMonth + '01')
Set @EndOfMonth = DateSubtract(day, 1,DateAdd(month, 1, @StartOfMonth))
```

The it depends on whether you are interested in those subscribed for the whole month or any part of the month.

This will get you those for the whole month

```
Select * From Subscriptions Where
StartDate <= @StartOfMonth and EndDate >= @EndOfMonth
```

Or this will get you those for any part of the month

```
Select * From Subsciptions Where
(@StartOfMonth Between StartDate and EndDate)
Or
(@EndOfMonth Between StartDate and EndDate)
```

Well something like that anyway.

Comment: I want to know all users who are subscribed any part of the month.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
DECLARE @subscriptionStart datetime;
DECLARE @subscriptionEnd datetime;
DECLARE @monthStart datetime;
DECLARE @monthEnd datetime;
SET @subscriptionStart = '20111120';
SET @subscriptionEnd = '20120310';
SET @monthStart = '20120201';
SET @monthEnd = (dateadd(day,-1* day(dateadd(month,1,@monthStart)),dateadd(month,1,@monthStart)));

SELECT CASE   
        WHEN @subscriptionStart <= @monthStart 
        AND  @subscriptionEnd   >= @monthEnd 
        THEN 'month between dates' 
        ELSE 'month not between dates' END AS result
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SET @SpecifiedDate = '2012/02/01'

SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Start_Date >= @SpecifiedDate
```

OR

```
WHERE Month(@SpecifiedDate) = MONTH(Start_Date) AND YEAR(@SpecifiedDate) = YEAR(Start_Date)
```

**You can use this**

```
WHERE Month(@SpecifiedDate) >= MONTH(Start_Date) AND Month(@SpecifiedDate) <= MONTH(End_Date)
```

But I prefer using the the full date (with the year, month and 01 as day). Thus I won't worry about the year since SQL will handle the filtering

```
WHERE @SpecifiedDate >= Start_Date AND @SpecifiedDate <= End_Date
```

Comment: Is that the 1st of Feb or the 2nd of January?

Comment: Simply, I want to know if a given month falls between two dates. That will allow me to count all users who are subscribed in a specified month. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is confusing. "I want to .... in the month of Feb" is not the same as what you are saying now